# PHP iteration foreach, omitting characters from last iteration

Tags: php, foreach, iteration

I'm tying to iterate through an array, assembling a string to return each time.

My question is how can I omit the comma on the last iteration of the array, or if there is only one element to the array? I'm not sure what this operation would be called as my coding skills are very rudimentary, so I've not had much luck searching for an answer. Even help knowing this basic detail would be much appreciated.

this is the result I'd like:

```
{ image : 'http://www.site.com/path/to/file/image1.jpg', title : 'Some title and caption' url : 'http://www.site.com/path/to/file/image1.jpg' },
{ image : 'http://www.site.com/path/to/file/image1.jpg', title : 'Some title and caption' url : 'http://www.site.com/path/to/file/image1.jpg' },
{ image : 'http://www.site.com/path/to/file/image1.jpg', title : 'Some title and caption' url : 'http://www.site.com/path/to/file/image1.jpg' }
```

Note the lack of a trailing comma.
Below is the php Im using to generate the strings. It will always include a trailing comma which is causing me all sorts of greif.

```
//snipit
$i = 1;
$a = '';  
foreach ($pages as $go)
{
    $title  = ($go['media_title'] == '') ? '&nbsp;' : $go['media_title'];
    $caption = ($go['media_caption'] == '') ? '&nbsp;' : $go['media_caption'];

    $a .= "{ image :'" . BASEURL . GIMGS . "/$go[media_file]', title : '{$title}, {$caption}', url: '" . BASEURL . GIMGS . "/$go[media_file]' }";
    $a .= ",\n";

$i++; 
return $a;
}
```

Many thanks for your experience, 

orionrush

Comment: oh please use JSON, like json_encode

Comment: you return statement is inside the for loop. is it type?

Comment: Gaurav - typo on my part thanks for flagging that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really use `json_encode()`.

```
$data = array();
foreach ($pages as $go) {
    $title  = ($go['media_title'] == '') ? '&nbsp;' : $go['media_title'];
    $caption = ($go['media_caption'] == '') ? '&nbsp;' : $go['media_caption'];

    $data[] = array(
        'image' => BASEURL . GIMGS . '/' . $go['media_file'],
        'title' => $title . ', ' . $caption,
        'url' => BASEURL . GIMGS . '/' . $go['media_file']
    );
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: ThiefMaster - I can see now why folks are pushing json here - And thanks for your answer being so appropriate for my situation.

Comment: Hey  - got locked out of my own comment! 
The output is on the right track, but generates a lot of extra quotes and backslashes:

{"image":"http:\/\/photolumiere.site:8888\/files\/gimgs\/1_photo-32.jpg","title":"&nbsp;, &nbsp;","url":"http:\/\/photolumiere.site:8888\/files\/gimgs\/1_photo-32.jpg"},

For my needs image title etc should not be quoted at all, yet the urls need to be in single quotes. Can you quickly show me how to format the output, or point me to a good technique?

Comment: Just spend a moment looking into json - its not unfortunately going to play nice as my output is going directly to javascript, and its not really an option to rewrite the code base to accept quoted keys etc. Im not able to vote you up but thanks for your help. Im going to have to go down the implode route.

Comment: If your output is "directly going to javascript" you can simply put something like `var stuff = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;` and it will work since JSON is a subset of JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

```
$a[] = "{ image :'" . BASEURL . GIMGS . "/$go[media_file]', title : '{$title}, {$caption}', url: '" . BASEURL . GIMGS . "/$go[media_file]' }";
```

and use it by

```
return implode(",\n", $a);
```

Comment: as I am outputing directly to javascript, json isn't unfortunately an option for me. This is the solution I ended up going with.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($pages as $go){
    $return[] = json_encode($go);
}

return implode(",\n", $return);
```

do what you like in the foreach, the implode will comma separate the lines like you want

Answer (score 0):

just chop the end off with substr:

```
return substr($a, 0, -3);
```